# How to implement alarm as a local notification in app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to implement alarm as a local notification in app My Sample code :

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Add this at the end of your code & make sure you select valid date & time for notification to fire up.